# LinkedIn picture url returns 404 not found

Tags: image, api, linkedin-api, profile

A LinkedIn profile picture url of the form http://m.c.lnkd.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/... sometimes returns a 404 not found. I can't consistently reproduce the issue but it seemed to occur on my incognito browser so I assume there is some cookie dependency that I am not aware of.

Does anyone know under what circumstances might a profile picture url not work?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm seeing the same.